# Does Maven automatically build other modules?

Tags: java, maven, module

I couldn't really find an answer anywhere to this particular question.

I have a (Maven) project consisting of multiple modules, let's say a `core` module (a jar) and a `webapp` module (a war).

When I run `mvn clean package` on my webapp, does it automatically always build the core first and will it pick up any changes in it? Do I have to run `mvn clean install` instead? Or do I have to run `mvn clean package/install` on my parent pom?

Does it matter if the parent/module is a release or a snapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with a so called `Multi Module Build` you should do everything what you like to do with your whole project from the parent level.
There you can do:

```
mvn clean package
```

than it will build all modules in the correct order (assuming you have defined the dependencies between them correct).

If you have such a multi module build all your modules incl. your parent should have the same version number. If you like to make a release of the whole you can simply start from the parent.

Comment: I'm using Maven Release to save me from the hassle of manually editing every pom.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build anything that's changed, upwards.  So, if you change core, then rebuild core, then rebuild your war.  If you've just changed your war, then you only need to rebuild your war.  Cleaning is generally good practice.  The reason not to do it would be if you're generating a bunch of entity classes, which takes a long time to redo.

I've seen a lot of mistakes because people forget to clean, and then some old piece of code is still active, even though they thought they'd deleted it.

Installing will put your latest build into your M2 repo, which is generally a good idea too.  You really can't go wrong with "mvn clean install"